# Передача объекта из одного сервлета другому. Java

Tags: java, веб-программирование, servlet, объекты, веб-сервер

Начал осваивать Java Servlets и на данный момент не могу реализовать следующую "идею":
Пользователь регестрируется на сайте и после заполнения всех полей его перенаправляет на страницу с его данными. На этой странице есть кнопка "Редактировать".
**Вопрос в следующем:**
***Каким образом мне передать объект UserProfile, который получается при регистрации пользователя в сервлет, который отвечает за редактирование данных?*** (На данный момент я пришел только к тому,что созданного пользователя кладем в мапу,и потом этого же пользователя достаем из этой мапы). Но я уверен,что все делается гораздо проще через setAttribute(), правда пока не разобрался,как именно.
Ниже привожу классы сервлетов,отвечающих за регистрацию и редактирование. Класс UserProfile - обычный класс,с полями пользователя, конструктором и сеттерами и геттерами.

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/registration", "/reg"})
public class SignUpServlet  extends HttpServlet {
    private UserProfile userProfile;


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Enter doGet SignUpServlet");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/registration.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Enter doPost SignUpServlet");

        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        String action = request.getParameter("action");

        if ("submit".equals(action)) {
            userProfile = new UserProfile();
            userProfile.setName(request.getParameter("name"));
            userProfile.setSecondName(request.getParameter("secondName"));
            userProfile.setBirthday(request.getParameter("birthday"));
            userProfile.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
            userProfile.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));
            SignInServlet.userMap.put((long) 0, userProfile);
            //изменить "порядок" добавления данных в мапу! задать нормальный идентификатор,и возможно,изменит ьего тип!
            request.setAttribute("userProfile", userProfile);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/userInfo.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }


    }



}
```

И сервлет, отвечающий редактирование:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/userProfile" })
public class UserInfoUpdateServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private UserProfile userProfile;

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Enter doGet UserInfoUpdateServlet");
        //вот таким образом объект я получаю,но не думаю,что это верно
        for (HashMap.Entry entry : SignInServlet.userMap.entrySet()) {
            if ((Long) entry.getKey() == 0) {
                userProfile = (UserProfile) entry.getValue();
                    System.out.println("Yahooo!");
                    request.setAttribute("userProfile", userProfile);
                    //request.getRequestDispatcher("/userInfo.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("blin!");
            }
        }
        //тщетные попытки получить объект.
        userProfile = (UserProfile) request.getSession().getAttribute("userProfile");

        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        request.getAttribute("userProfile");
        switch (action == null ? "info" : action) {
        case "update":
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/userInfoUpdate.jsp").forward(request, response);
            break;
        case "info":
        default:
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/userInfo.jsp").forward(request, response);
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Enter doPost UserInfoUpdateServlet");

        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        String action = request.getParameter("action");

        if ("submit".equals(action)) {
            userProfile = new UserProfile();
            userProfile.setName(request.getParameter("name"));
            userProfile.setSecondName(request.getParameter("secondName"));
            userProfile.setBirthday(request.getParameter("birthday"));
            userProfile.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
            userProfile.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));
        }

        request.setAttribute("userProfile", userProfile);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/userInfo.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

А так же прикрепляю JSP страницы регистрации и редактирования:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<!-- Подключение js и css только таким образом! -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    <%@include file="/resources/js/login.js"%>
</script>

<style>
    <%@include file="/resources/css/login.css"%>
</style>
<head>
<title>Update</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="login-page">
<div class="form">
        <form method="post" action="registration?action=submit" class="login-form">
                    <input type="text" name="name" value="${userProfile.name}" placeholder="Имя" />
                    <input type="text" name="secondName" value="${userProfile.secondName}" placeholder="Фамилия" />
                    <input type="date" name="birthday" value="${userProfile.birthday}" placeholder="Дата Рождения" />
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="${userProfile.email}" placeholder="email" />
                    <input type="password" name="password" value="${userProfile.password}" placeholder="Пароль" />
            <button type="submit">Регистрация</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Редактирование:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Update</title>
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <jsp:useBean id="userProfile" scope="request" type="Authorization.UserProfile"/>
    <form method="post" action="userProfile?action=submit">
                    <input type="text" name="name" value="${userProfile.name}" placeholder="Имя" />
                    <input type="text" name="secondName" value="${userProfile.secondName}" placeholder="Фамилия" />
                    <input type="date" name="birthday" value="${userProfile.birthday}" placeholder="Дата Рождения" />
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="${userProfile.email}" placeholder="email" />
                    <input type="password" name="password" value="${userProfile.password}" placeholder="Пароль" />
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Сам профиль UserInfo.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Данные пользователя</title>
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <h3>Персональные данные: </h3>
    <jsp:useBean id="userProfile" scope="request" type="Authorization.UserProfile"/>
    <tr>
    <h1>${userProfile.name} &nbsp; ${userProfile.secondName}</h1>
    <h1>Дата Рождения: ${userProfile.birthday}</h1>
    <h1>Email: ${userProfile.email}</h1>
        <td><a href="userProfile?action=update">Редактировать</a></td>
    </tr>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

На данный момент реализовано все для одного пользователя,чтобы отладить функционал, так что на то,что в мапе ключ айди = 0, не стоит обращать внимания.

За конструктивную критику по поводу самой реализации и написания кода буду благодарен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь сессией (HttpSession):

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Enter doPost SignUpServlet");

    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    String action = request.getParameter("action");

    if ("submit".equals(action)) {
        userProfile = new UserProfile();
        userProfile.setName(request.getParameter("name"));
        userProfile.setSecondName(request.getParameter("secondName"));
        userProfile.setBirthday(request.getParameter("birthday"));
        userProfile.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
        userProfile.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));
        request.getSession().setAttribute("userProfile", userProfile);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/userInfo.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }


}
```

Ну и получение:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Enter doGet UserInfoUpdateServlet");

    // можно прям в JSP странице получить нужный элемент, но лучше сделаем атрибутом запроса

    String action = request.getParameter("action");
    switch (action == null ? "info" : action) {
    case "update":
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/userInfoUpdate.jsp").forward(request, response);
        break;
    case "info":
    default:
        request.setAttribute("userProfile", (UserProfile) request.getSession().getAttribute("userProfile"));
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/userInfo.jsp").forward(request, response);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробовал сейчас Ваш ответ: 
В doPost без `request.setAttribute("userProfile", userProfile);` данные пользователя не открываются,так как бин не объявлен. А если использовать и setAttribute и getSession, то данные открываются, но редактирование все равно не идет. Выходит ошибка:  
`java.lang.InstantiationException: bean userProfile not found within scope`

Comment: @МишаковАлександр с этими не работал, не могу подсказать. Знаю что через сессию такие данные легко можно передать, без всяких бинов и т.д.

Comment: да,я тоже читал про это, но реализовать не получается, поэтому обратился сюда. Что я уже только не перепробовал,но пока не понимаю,в чем ошибка. Спасибо.

Comment: @МишаковАлександр я думаю штука в использовании бинов. Попробуйте вообще без них.

Comment: В данном случае `request.getSession().setAttribute("userProfile", userProfile);` "userProfile" - это бин,то есть объект. К бинам спринга вообще никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: @МишаковАлександр ну тогда все должно работать.

Comment: В том то и беда,что да,должно,но не работает.

Comment: Да, данный способ решает проблему. А заключалась она в следующем: Ссылка,при переходе на страницу данных пользователя `/registration?action=submit`,вместо положенного `userProfile?action=info`